# Updating values of one nested dictionary to another having list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, pandas-groupby, dictionary-comprehension

say we have two nested dictionaries:

```
dict1={'s1':{'A':{'C':'3','D':'4'},'B':{'E':'5','F':'6'}}}

dict2 = {'s1':[{'C':'3a','D':'4a'},{'C':'3b','D':'4b'}], 'B': {'E':'5a','F':'6a'}}
```

I can replace the value in dict1 based on a key with value dict2

```
dict1['E']=dict2['E']
```

which will result in ..

```
dict1={'s1':{'A':{'C':'3','D':'4'},'B':{'E':'5a','F':'6'}}}
```

**Now** I want to find, C and D in dict1 and replace with list of C and D from dict2
Output should be like:

```
dict1={'s1':{'A':[{'C':'3a','D':'4a'},{'C':'3b','D':'4b'}],'B':{'E':'5a','F':'6'}}}
```

without affecting original keys A and B in dict 1
we can also create a new dictionary copying dict1 and make modifications..
but the structure of dict1 should remain intact

Comment: What's the type of `dict2`?`Set` or `Dict`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly, you haven't written `dict2` properly, it neither a dictionary nor a set. Maybe this (`dict2={'s1':[{'C':'3a','D':'4a'},{'C':'3b','D':'4b'}], 'B': {'E':'5a','F':'6a'}}`) is what you meant.

If this assumption is correct, the you can change the value of key A in dict1 this way:

```
dict1['s1']['A'] = dict2['s1']
print(dict1)
```

> Result

```
{'s1': {'A': [{'C': '3a', 'D': '4a'}, {'C': '3b', 'D': '4b'}], 'B': {'E': '5', 'F': '6'}}}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing the mistake, have edited the question. Also thanks for thee solution